# Need regex pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to make regex pattern for :
This is the user-defined welcome message.
It can be modified using the \'General Items\' item under the \'Creation\' menu.
**Login Name:** %empName%
**Last Login Time:** %lastLoginTime%
**Last Login IP:** %lastLoginIP%
**Recent Failed Login Attempts:** %loginAttempts%

I tried patterns testing over https://regex101.com/   but all are failing.

Can someone help me with regex pattern for above.

Comment: Post what you've attempted so far

Comment: Patterns for retrieving which data's?

Comment: I do not have downvoted. But for your information, its getting downvotes because the question is not clear, is not posted with what he have tried & so on. And can be also closed with flag - **unclear what you're asking**

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want something like

```
([^:]*):[^%]*%([^%]*)%
```

This:

```
([^:]*) -- everything before the first : is the _description_
:       -- followed by a : character
[^%]*   -- followed by any number of non-% characters
%       -- followed by a % character (beginning of token)
([^%]*) -- captures the _token_ between %..%
%       -- followed by a % character (end of token)
```

The first capturing group is the *description* and the second is the *token*. The token itself will refer to a value. In that sense, the token is also the *key* which corresponds to a particular value.

[Try it out here!](https://regex101.com/r/GvfFHF/1)

Comment: Do you know which of the data is required or trying to fetch using pattern from the text given above? I do not think that there will be `%` at the starting & ending as you assumed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really unclear.

If you want to find the variable names, you need to use: `%([^%]+)%`. It catches the entire `%blahBlah%` sequence, which can be replaced later with relevant information. It makes sure that `%%` without nothing in between is considered invalid.

If we consider `%blahBlah%` to be proper variable name, then the regex should look like:

```
%([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9]*)%
```

with the meaning: any sequence of underscore, uppercase and lowercase letters and digits, where the first character is not a digit.